# Why can't a change the image's src attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code in question.

```
$( ".icon-image" )[index].attr('src', '/folder/newimage.jpg');
```

If I try to use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like above it's undefined.

```
 $( ".icon-image" ).attr('src', '/folder/newimage.jpg');
```

However, if I do that it changes all the img tags/class name to the same image. Which I do not want. I only want to change the the image one at a time, when I decide, while I loop through with the index.

Why can't this simple functionality, where I decide which element of the array should change, can not be achieved?

Comment: You don't want to alter the attribute value, you want to alter the property value. use `.prop`

Comment: @SterlingArcher: In this particular case, it comes to the same thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just read your answer, facepalmed. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `[]` to index into a jQuery set, what you get back is a DOM element, not a jQuery set. But `attr` is a jQuery function, not a DOM function.

Either use `eq` so you're getting a jQuery set containing just that one element, and can use `attr`:

```
$( ".icon-image" ).eq(index).attr('src', '/folder/newimage.jpg');
```

(Or `.prop('src', ...)`, in this particular case it comes to the same thing.)

...or use `[]` and use the reflected DOM property `src` on the resulting DOM element:

```
$( ".icon-image" )[index].src = '/folder/newimage.jpg';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) because it is the easiest way to select an indexed item from a jQuery collection of items, especially if you're used to using 0 based indexes -

```
$( ".icon-image" ).eq(0).attr('src', '/folder/newimage.jpg');
```

You would use the same number that you would use in your `[index]` above (or a variable).

Comment: Yes, but ***why***? *What* without *why* is not particularly helpful.

Comment: Bear in mind the difference between `prop()` and `attr()`; though I'm not sure if it's an issue with `<img />` elements and the `src`.

Comment: Yep @DavidThomas, I almost always use `.prop()` for booleans and `.attr()` for strings, but there are some exceptions. The use of `prop()` still has things left to desire.